# Different style in Conservation of momentum in two cases

Tags: momentum, collision

What are the differences between the process of conservation of momentum in case of:  i) A ball hitting a concrete ground and rebounding back high
     ii) A ball hitting a sand ground and keeping still

I want to know both the cases descriptively

Answer (score 0):

There is no *process* of conservation of momentum. Total momentum in the absence of forces is always conserved.

Regarding your examples, it depends in how much detail you want to study them. In a real system, momentum can be transferred to the deformation of the ball or ground, or to the air, or momentum can go to the earth which won't move much, because of the huge difference in mass.

However in many situations we are not interested in all these details and would consider a subsystem with fewer variables where momentum might not be conserved. For instance we could assume the ball to bounce elastically from a rigid wall ignoring anything else.